# VSTO find ContentControls of a Word Document

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

Is there a way to find all ContentControls of a WordDocument (including ContentControls in Headers, Footers, TextBoxes ...) using VSTO?

Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.Document.ContentContols returns only the ContentControls of the Main-Document, not the one inside the Headers/Footer.

Answer (score 3):

Copied from http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/vsto/thread/0eb0af6f-17db-4f98-bc66-155db691fd70

```
public static List<ContentControl> GetAllContentControls(Document wordDocument)
    {
      if (null == wordDocument)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("wordDocument");

      List<ContentControl> ccList = new List<ContentControl>();

      // The code below search content controls in all
      // word document stories see http://word.mvps.org/faqs/customization/ReplaceAnywhere.htm
      Range rangeStory;
      foreach (Range range in wordDocument.StoryRanges)
      {
        rangeStory = range;
        do
        {
          try
          {
            foreach (ContentControl cc in rangeStory .ContentControls)
            {
              ccList.Add(cc);
            }
            foreach (Shape shapeRange in rangeStory.ShapeRange)
            {
              foreach (ContentControl cc in shapeRange.TextFrame.TextRange.ContentControls)
              {
                ccList.Add(cc);
              }
            }
          }
          catch (COMException) { }
          rangeStory = rangeStory.NextStoryRange;

        }
        while (rangeStory != null);
      }
      return ccList;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach (Word.ContentControl contentcontrol in this.Application.ActiveDocument.ContentControls)
{
    //Some action on all contentcontrol objects
}
```

If that doesn't work try to iterate on all ranges (for contentcontrols) in a document's [StoryRanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb178138.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I'm dealing with the same problem, but driving Word from MATLAB. This page by a Word MVP solved the problem for me:

http://www.word.mvps.org/FAQs/MacrosVBA/FindReplaceAllWithVBA.htm

Essentially, you have to:

1. Loop over all Document.StoryRanges to get the first range of each story type.
2. Within each range, do your job on range.ContentControls.
3. range = range.NextStoryRange.
4. Repeat 2-4 until range is empty.